# Restore backup from iPhone SE (iOS 13.4.1) to iPhone 6 (iOS 12.4.6)

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, restore, downgrade

Got two iPhones:

- iPhone SE on 13.4.1
- iPhone 6 on 12.4.6

As far as I understand, both iOS versions are the latest ones for the respective model.

When trying to restore a backup from SE to 6, iTunes complains that the backup is not compatible and I should update the iPhone.

Kind of makes sense. To be honest, until yesterday I thought that iPhone 6 is newer than SE, but it seems that I was wrong there.

Is there a way to get "stuff" from SE to 6? In an ideal world, of course that would mean all apps and all data. But probably there is no sensible way to downgrade everything.

Would icould be able to serve as a "logical backup" for photos etc.?

Comment: Try also this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t get Apple to restore a newer OS to an older one. This is by design. Short of a jailbreak you will need a device that runs iOS 13.4.1 or newer to restore the data and then examine / export / sync or write by hand or manually any data for RE-entry in the 12.4.6 device.

iCloud sync is a very good way to go if you can borrow or rent a device assuming you don’t have both in hand and working.